# Google Ad Data not showing in Google Analytics 4 API for only one Property

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-cloud-console

When calling the Google Analytics API for one of our properties, it's returning 0 every time even though there is data there, but for other properties, it's working fine. Plus, when I make the date range a whole previous month, it works fine.

Has anyone had this issue before? I'm presuming its to do with Google Sampling the data, but how is there a way to get around that or speed up the proccess.

Note:

- Date range is 2023-11-01 to 2023-11-30 (Whole of last month)
- I've made sure Google Ads is linked in GA4 Admin.
- I can see Paid Ad data in my GA4 Dashboard.

> ```
> const fetchDataFromAnalytics = async (request, propertyID, token, type) => {
>       try {
>         const response = await fetch(
>    `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${propertyID}:runReport`,
>           {
>             method: 'POST',
>             headers: {
>               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>               Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
>             },
>             body: request,
>           }
>         );
>         const data = await response.json();
>         return data;
>       } catch (error) {
>         console.error('Fetch error:', error.message); // Log the error message
>         throw error;
>       }
>     };
>
> const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
>             metrics: [
>               {
>                 name: 'advertiserAdClicks',
>               },
>               {
>                 name: 'advertiserAdCost',
>               },
>               {
>                 name: 'advertiserAdCostPerClick',
>               },
>               {
>                 name: 'advertiserAdCostPerConversion',
>               },
>             ],
>             dimensions: [
>               {
>                 name: 'campaignName',
>               },
>             ],
>             dateRanges: [
>               {
>                 startDate: newStartDate,
>                 endDate: newEndDate,
>               },
>             ],
>             keepEmptyRows: true,
>           });
> ```

**Returned Row Data**

```
[
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "(direct)"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "(organic)"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "(referral)"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "Abandoned Cart"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```